# Multiple contacts for a single person?

Tags: integration, contact, database

I'm integrating Salesforce with a system that will act as the source of employee records.  In the source system, each employee human can be represented by multiple employee records - one per organisation unit that they have worked in.  Each employee record will have its own ID and, in a separate field, a common ID for that human.

These separate records need to be maintained so that their old contact details are available, plus the history of cases that they raised when in different parts of the organisation.  Integration is via an ETL tool.

The question is, do we create:

1. One Contact record per human employee, then somehow store the
   historic contact details in a separate object, or
2. One Contact record per employee record

Views?  Considerations?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, simply enable [Contacts to Multiple Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=shared_contacts_overview.htm&type=5). This would allow you to store all previous relationships plus any related information for each organization. This also allows you to have one record per person, which allows a global historical view of a person.